# How do i remove linefeeds after matching string until next match in linux?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

Hi and thanks in advance for reading and maybe help me. 
I have a log like the example under and i want all text from the id, time and date to be in one line until next id, time and date. i have tried some examples but not found the right one yet... 
Here is the text. It is in latin1 i think thats why it looks litle funny.

```
1334361 05:35:47 15-10-15  Talgrupp : Sk�n RAPS-03
                           Adr : Burl�vsbadet
                           Ort : 
                           Omr : M170
                           Kommun : Burl�v


                           Brand ute - fordon
                           Personbil
                           �vrigt

                           Till�ggsinfo : 
                           �rende Id : 2
                            A
1334361 05:36:47 15-10-15  Talgrupp : Sk�n RAPS-03
                           Adr : Burl�vsbadet
                           Ort : 
                           Omr : M170
                           Kommun : Burl�v


                           Brand ute - fordon
                           Personbil
                           �vrigt

                           Till�ggsinfo : 
                           �rende Id : 2
                           P`
0742963 09:12:14 15-10-15  �nr : 5738690
                           VG�t RAPS-32
                           Trafikolycka - flera fordon
                           Personbil


                           LV 200
                           Ort : 
                           Sk�vde
                           RAPS 32
                           X=6494376 Y=1395320
                           Nyckel : 
                           Omfattning : L�g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bashscript did the trick for me. Maybe helps someone else.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Filvariabel
cd /medianas/html
fil="/medianas/html/extra.flt"
logfil="/medianas/html/fltlog/extra.flt.hist"
originalfil="/medianas/html/fltlog/extra.flt.orig"
pocfil="/medianas/html/pocsaglog.flt"
pocbak="/medianas/html/fltlog/pocsaglog.bak.flt"

[[ -f pocsaglog.flt ]] && sed -i 's/nr :.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-    9][0-9]//' ${pocfil}

# Replace Pos: with X=
[[ -f ${fil} ]] && sed -i 's/Pos: /X=/g' ${fil}
# Replace ,_ followed by 7 numbers, with Y=
[[ -f ${fil} ]] && sed -i 's/\(, \)\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/ Y=\2/g' ${fil}
# Add NN to numbers in id
[[ -f ${fil} ]] && sed -i 's/\(Mapp Id : \)\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-    9][0-9][0-9]\)/NN\2/g' ${fil} 
[[ -f ${fil} ]] && sed -i 's/\(nr : \)\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-  9][0-9]\)//g' ${fil}

[[ -f $fil ]] && cat $fil >> $originalfil
# Deletes empty rows
if [ -f ${fil} ]  
then
grep -v '^\s*$' ${fil} > ${fil}.test
# Delete linefeeds
tr '\r\n' ' ' < $fil.test > $fil.labb
# Deletes all spaces and replace with one space 
tr -s " " < ${fil}.labb > ${fil}.test
[[ -f ${fil}.test ]] && sed -i '/F*rlarm/d' ${fil}.test
# Take away Änr: and seven numbers
sed -i 's/?nr:.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]//' ${fil}.test 
# Make blank line before pocnr
sed -i 's/\ [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/\n&/g' ${fil}.test
# Delete tmpfiles and original
[[ -f ${fil} ]] && rm ${fil}
# Delete space where line starts with it. 
sed -i 's/^ *//' ${fil}.test
[[ -f $fil.test ]] && cat $fil.test >> $logfil
#   [[ -f ${fil}.test ]] && rm ${fil}.test
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

with awk:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+/ && NR>1 {print ""}; END {print ""}; {$1=$1; printf "%s", $0}' file
```

That prints every line without a newline, and for lines beginning with digits and after the last line, print a newline. I added `$1=$1` which forces awk to rewrite the line using the output field separator, by default a single space.

```
1334361 05:35:47 15-10-15 Talgrupp : Sk�n RAPS-03Adr : Burl�vsbadetOrt :Omr : M170Kommun : Burl�vBrand ute - fordonPersonbil�vrigtTill�ggsinfo :�rende Id : 2A
1334361 05:36:47 15-10-15 Talgrupp : Sk�n RAPS-03Adr : Burl�vsbadetOrt :Omr : M170Kommun : Burl�vBrand ute - fordonPersonbil�vrigtTill�ggsinfo :�rende Id : 2P`
0742963 09:12:14 15-10-15 �nr : 5738690VG�t RAPS-32Trafikolycka - flera fordonPersonbilLV 200Ort :Sk�vdeRAPS 32X=6494376 Y=1395320Nyckel :Omfattning : L�g
```

Comment: Thanks! Still a lot of space in the lines but something to looking in to.

Comment: I want the white spaces to ga away to. Just leave one space.

Comment: Better but still i cant get it right on my computer. The text file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nd7ryq6xgzwn3c/extra.flt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to regular expressions, something like this
`(?m)(?:\r?\n|\r)^\s+(?=[^\S\r\n])`

**Edit** this `(?:\r?\n|\r)\s+(?=[^\S\r\n])` does the same thing.

Would result in this

```
1334361 05:35:47 15-10-15  Talgrupp : Sk�n RAPS-03 Adr : Burl�vsbadet Ort :  Omr : M170 Kommun : Burl�v Brand ute - fordon Personbil �vrigt Till�ggsinfo :  �rende Id : 2 A
1334361 05:36:47 15-10-15  Talgrupp : Sk�n RAPS-03 Adr : Burl�vsbadet Ort :  Omr : M170 Kommun : Burl�v Brand ute - fordon Personbil �vrigt Till�ggsinfo :  �rende Id : 2 P`
0742963 09:12:14 15-10-15  �nr : 5738690 VG�t RAPS-32 Trafikolycka - flera fordon Personbil LV 200 Ort :  Sk�vde RAPS 32 X=6494376 Y=1395320 Nyckel :  Omfattning : L�g
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks very promissing. Can you please give me an example in python or bash how to use it on a text-file? I ve tried some examples but cant get it to work. Can i somehow attache a textfile here in the forum?

Comment: @StefanRydberg  -  I think you can link to a text file, not sure if  you can attach one here. I don't really know Python, or what regex engine bash uses. But, you could try this `(?:\r?\n|\r)\s+(?=[^\S\r\n])` and see if it works. I just took out the multi-line modifier `(?m)` and the beginning of line construct `^`. It does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of answer to do the thing i wanted. So i have to do as my teachers allways told us, take small steps ahead until you solved it. It became a bash-script that solved it finally. Maybe someone else need it so i post it here. Basic stuff but works.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Filvariabel
cd /medianas/html
fil="extra.flt"
# Tar bort tomma rader
if [ -f ${fil} ]  
    then
    grep -v '^\s*$' $fil > $fil.test
    # Tar bort linefeed
    tr '\r\n' ' ' < $fil.test > $fil.labb
    # Tar bort alla space och ersätter med en space
    tr -s " " < $fil.labb > $fil.test
    sed 's/\ [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/\n&/g' $fil.test >     $fil.klar
    # Tar bort tmpfiler och original
    rm $fil.test
    rm $fil.labb
    [[ -f $fil ]] && rm $fil
    # Tar bort inledande blank per rad
    sed -i 's/^ *//' $fil.klar
fi
/home/stefan/larm/fltmap-radio2.py &> /dev/null
```